# Can't access procedure in System unit

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm using Delphi 11.3 Patch 1.

I tried to implement the function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853069/4323109), but the compiler gives an error for an undeclared identifier `_AbstractError`. I can see this procedure in the `System` unit, but I can't refer to its pointer, or call it directly.

What am I missing?

Comment: RTL functions that begin with an underscore are reserved for the compiler/RTL's internal use, you can't access/call them directly.  What you might try doing is declaring a small utility class that has an abstract method and then grab the pointer to `_AbstractError` from that class's VMT.